# Checking XML Signature +ECC-Algorithm

Tags: java, android, xml-signature

I've reached a point in my current Android-Project, that requires verifying an XML-Signature with a .pdf file (the pdf File is signed in the XMl file)
and i encountered one major problem. It is related with absolutley NOT beeing able to use the iaik-libaries:

The Signature is made with the ECC-Algorithm (Eliptic curves), which standard java libaries cannot handle.
Does anyone know a way to deal with these signatures?

So what i am looking for is either another libarie or a workaround for the javax-Problem.

Many Thanks for any idea!

**Additional Info:**

- I know about Apache Santuario, but i can not use it, because it
  containt classes that would be added to javax, and the DalvikVM does
  not allow that.
- I know it's easy to do it with iaik, but it is not an option due to
  licence-issues (+ the javax-problem).
- I do not post any code, because it cannot be done my way, i'm totaly stuck and i need new Ideas from scratch :/

Comment: [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Elliptic+Curve+Key+Pair+Generation+and+Key+Factories) can do eliptic curves at least - it's already included in platform - **but** that version may very likely be severely gimped - that issue can however be solved by using a refactored version, e.g. [SpongyCastle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/).